# Having problems getting a PHP regex to match

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Here is my problem. It's probably a simple fix. I have a regex that I am using to replace a url BBCode. What I have right now that is not working looks like this.

```
<?php
$input_string = '[url=www.test.com]Test[url]';
$regex = '/\[url=(.+?)](.+?)\[\/url]/is';
$replacement_string = '<a href="$1">$2</a>';
echo preg_replace($regex, $replacement_string, $input_string);
?>
```

This currently outputs the original $input_string, while I would like it to output the following.

```
<a href="www.test.com">Test</a>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Your Reyes is looking for `/url` yet your demo doesn't include it. Is that a typo?

Comment: What you are missing is that you should not parse structured languages with regular expressions. There are bbcode parsers for PHP available.

Comment: asside from the fact that there are bbcode PECL extensions available, are there any other reasons that i should not use regex to do this?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) rather famous answer is the reason - as @Tomalak said, "you should not parse structured languages with regular expressions". If regex works for you in your situation, then it's fine, but regexes aren't generally a robust tool to use to parse "structured languages".

Comment: ha. okay, but I am not parsing the HTML itself...which this answer seems to be addressing.

Comment: i can see a security hole however where the poster could slip js into the anchor tag. the final regex will have to be a bit more complicated.

Comment: That is why using a regex for this kind of thing makes it hard: when you have to support corner cases and think about all the subtle ways your input could change.

Comment: changed the url grabbing regex to use [^"] instead of a period, so that the user cannot add any JavaScript to the anchor tag.

Comment: @dqhendricks: That *might* stop JavaScript (what about single quotes?), but try running your code against this link: http://www.google.com/search?q="nice%20try"

Comment: single quotes won't break the double quoted string. if they did, I would replace with [^"|']

Comment: not sure what that google search is supposed to link me to?

Comment: The point is, for every sophisticated smug regex you come up with, there will be a comparatively easy attack to knock it over. The problem of parsing bbcode is solved, why do want to roll you own parser? Bit-by-bit your regexes will become bloated, brittle and unmaintainable monsters with every corner case you work into them, and in the end it still won't be 100% safe. Apart from that, in terms if grammar complexity, bbcode is just like HTML, only with square brackets.

Comment: can the PECL BBCode parser do something like this? '[code]blah[/code]' = '<p class="code_block">'.highlight_string('blah').'</p>'?

Comment: and if so, can you prevent it from parsing anything between the code tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$input_string = '[url=www.test.com]Test[/url]';
$regex = '/\[url=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/url\]/is';
$replacement_string = '<a href="$1">$2</a>';
echo preg_replace($regex, $replacement_string, $input_string);
?>
```

- In your BBCode string, I closed the
  `[url]` properly.
- I escaped a `]` in the regex (not sure if that was an actual problem).

Note that `[url]http://example.org[/url]` is also a valid way to make a link in BBCode.

You should listen to the comments suggesting you use an existing BBCode parser.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line as follows:

`$regex = '/[url=(.+?)](.+?)[url]/is';`

OK, the formatting is not proper. While I figure it out, see this: http://pastebin.com/6pF0FEbA

Comment: Dam*ed backslahes. I posted @ Pastebin. It works, but I could not paste it properly here :-/